# Array manipulation with two sets of array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Lets say, i have

```
$color_options = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ];
$color_list = [];
```

The size of the color list is variable, which means could be anything (e.g. could be 1, could be 10,etc).

Lets say the size is 10,
How do i paste in the `$color_options` in the `$color_list`, so that
in `$color_list`  i would have,

- 4 'red'
- 3 'green'
- 3 'blue'

Thank you

Comment: Remember Key => Value Pairs $key = 4; $value = 'red'; then $color_list[$key] = $value;

I am not sure what you are asking though....

Comment: you can use `associative array` for the same

Comment: Can you give me an example? @MackProgramsAlot

Comment: Here I have a list of my friends and their ages:

    $friends = ['Tom'=>21, 'Phil'=>12, 'Paul'=>81];

In this case our keys are the names (Strings) and our values are their age (integers)

Comment: Suppose that `$color_list = 1` then you want green form `$color_options`, am I right?

Comment: @Irfan : $color_options = [ 'red' , 'green', 'blue' ];

if $color_list size is 5
$color_list = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green' ];

Comment: @Irfan lol I don't understand it so if you do go for it

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot: Hm, i do understand the key value pair, but how do i implement it in my case..
Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need 2 loops/indexes - so you continue looping through `$color_options` (returning to index 0 when reaching the end) and stopping the entire process when you reach the end of `$color_list` is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, exactly.
But how to achieve that?
@DaveCoast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$color_options = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue'];
$color_list_size = 5; 
$color_list = [];
$zeroOneOrTwo = 0;
for($i=0;$i<$color_list_size;$i++){
     $zeroOneOrTwo =  ($zeroOneOrTwo > 2) ? 0 : $zeroOneOrTwo;
     $color_list[] = $color_options[$zeroOneOrTwo];
     $zeroOneOrTwo++;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks.
I didn't think this way before..

Its great to use ternary operation as well.

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot, Good you are understand his problem, for you vote up!